# The TargetType for Line in style doesn't work in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have the following code:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Line">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="3"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Line X1="20" X2="500" Y1="50" Y2="50"></Line>
    <Line X1="20" X2="500" Y1="100" Y2="100"></Line>
    <Line X1="20" X2="500" Y1="150" Y2="150"></Line>
</Grid>
```

[image]

You could see the screenshoot, the `StrokeDashArray` property value in the style only appled to the first line. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue, but I'm not sure what caused this unexpected behavior. I'll ask the team about this issue. As a workaround, you could use StaticResource for sharing the value of StrokeDashArray.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Line">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <x:String x:Key="strokeArray">3</x:String>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Line X1="20" X2="500" Y1="50" Y2="50" StrokeDashArray="{StaticResource strokeArray}"></Line>
    <Line X1="20" X2="500" Y1="100" Y2="100" StrokeDashArray="{StaticResource strokeArray}"></Line>
    <Line X1="20" X2="500" Y1="150" Y2="150" StrokeDashArray="{StaticResource strokeArray}"></Line>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The team confirmed this is an issue and has fired an issue in github, you can track it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1784).