# Using StrokeDashArray in UWP charting-app

Tags: c#, charts, uwp, polyline

I'm trying to make a chart in an UWP-app (using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting) in while multiple dashed lines should show up. However, only the FIRST line is dashed, the second and third are solid.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?
Below is my XAML-code and code-behind. The thing I don't get is: if the Polyline-property StrokeThickness is working for all three lines (they are all reasonably thick), then why is the Polyline-property StrokeDashArray working only for the first line??

Joslan

```
<Page
x:Class="TestApp2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApp2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Charting="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LineSeriesStyle1" TargetType="Charting:LineSeries">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="PolylineStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="Polyline">
                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Charting:LineSeries">
                    <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                        <Polyline Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Charting:Chart x:Name="LineChart" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="400" Height="400">
        <Charting:Chart.Axes>
            <Charting:LinearAxis x:Name="Xas" Orientation="X" Location="Bottom" Interval="1" ShowGridLines="True" Title="X-as" CanDrag="True"/>
            <Charting:LinearAxis x:Name="Yas" Orientation="Y" Location="Left" Interval="1" ShowGridLines="True"/>
        </Charting:Chart.Axes>
        <Charting:LineSeries x:Name="Line0" Style="{StaticResource LineSeriesStyle1}" IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y"/>

        <Charting:LineSeries x:Name="Line1" Style="{StaticResource LineSeriesStyle1}" IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y"/>
        <Charting:LineSeries x:Name="Line2" Style="{StaticResource LineSeriesStyle1}" IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y"/>
    </Charting:Chart>

</Grid>
```

My code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace TestApp2
{
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
public List l0 { get; set; } = new List();
public List l1 { get; set; } = new List();
public List l2 { get; set; } = new List();

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        l0.Add(new Point(10, 20));
        l0.Add(new Point(11, 21));
        l0.Add(new Point(12, 22));
        l0.Add(new Point(13, 23));
        Line0.ItemsSource=l0;
        
        l1.Add(new Point(10, 30));
        l1.Add(new Point(11, 31));
        l1.Add(new Point(12, 32));
        l1.Add(new Point(13, 33));
        Line1.ItemsSource = l1;

        l2.Add(new Point(10, 40));
        l2.Add(new Point(11, 41));
        l2.Add(new Point(12, 42));
        l2.Add(new Point(13, 43));
        Line2.ItemsSource = l2;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code. Just as you mentioned, the `LineSeriesStyle1` only applied to the first line.  It is a confirmed issue, you could find the issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1784).

You could set the value of `StrokeDashArray` property in `Polyline` tag in the `LineSeriesStyle1` style to resolve the problem.

Or, you could find another solution referring to the [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419033/the-targettype-for-line-in-style-doesnt-work-in-uwp).

Comment: Thx YanGu. I see the issue has been around a long time. Guess I'll have to wait till the team has a look at it...